# ajax in spring security

Tags: jsf, spring-security

I using spring security+JSF+primefaces
in custom login, i put a command button
but command button no workin ...
 and when in p:commandbutton ----------> ajax="false" --------->  is work!
and when used f:ajax in jsf(core) --------> no work
and i use in spring security.xml file :

**test.xhtml**   ----> jsf(core) --------> no work

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html
            PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>faces-request</title>           
    </head>
    <body>
    <h:form>
        <center>
            <h:outputText id="outtxt" value="#{authentiocationBean.ajaxTest}"/><br/>
            <h:inputText id="intxt" value="#{authentiocationBean.ajaxTest}"/><br/>
            <h:commandButton value="Submit">
                <f:ajax execute="intxt" render="outtxt"/>
            </h:commandButton>        
        </center>
    </h:form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**Spring_security.xml:**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">


    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/Admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/user/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN')"/>           
        <form-login login-page="/login.xhtml"
                    authentication-failure-url="/Fail.xhtml?error"/>
        <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE"
                invalidate-session="true"
                logout-success-url="/login.xhtml"/>
        <session-management session-authentication-error-url="/401.xhtml" session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login.xhtml"/>
        </session-management>

        <remember-me key="myAppKey"/>
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/AccDe.xhtml"/>
        <headers>
            <xss-protection/>
            <frame-options/>
            <cache-control/>
            <content-type-options/>
        </headers>
        <csrf/>

    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="myDataSource"
                               users-by-username-query="select username, password, active from users where username=?"
                               authorities-by-username-query="select us.username, ur.authority from users us, user_roles ur
                    where us.user_id = ur.user_id and us.username =?  "
                    />
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" hash="sha-256"/>

        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>


    <bean id="passwordEncoder"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
        <!--org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder       for salt!-->
        <constructor-arg value="256"/>
    </bean>



</beans:beans>
```

**LoginPage:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>

    <title>faces-request</title>     
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form prependId="false" id="formLogin">
        <center>
            <p:panelGrid style="border-width: 0px;" columns="2">
                UserName:
                <p:inputText required="true" id="j_username"/>
                Password:
                <p:password required="true" id="j_password"/>
            </p:panelGrid>               
            <p:commandButton type="submit" id="login" action="#{authentiocationBean.doLogin()}" value="Login"/>
            <p:outputLabel for="_spring_security_remember_me" value="Remember me: "/>
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="_spring_security_remember_me"/>
            <br/>
        </center>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**AuthentiocationBean class**

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;


/**
 * @author Admin
 */
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean
public class AuthentiocationBean {
    public String ajaxTest = "Test";
    boolean isLogged = false;
    public String role = "ROLE_ADMIN";
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String name = auth.getName();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String doLogin() throws IOException, ServletException {
        isLogged = true;
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext context = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest()).getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check");
        dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(), (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        // It's OK to return null here because Faces is just going to exit.
        return null;
    }

    public void doLogout() {
//        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
//       return "/logout.xhtml";
//       return null;
    }

    public boolean isLogged() {
        return isLogged;
    }

    public void setLogged(boolean logged) {
        isLogged = logged;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getAjaxTest() {
        return ajaxTest;
    }

    public void setAjaxTest(String ajaxTest) {
        this.ajaxTest = ajaxTest;
    }


}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's just a login page, so why bother with AJAX?

I have integrated Spring 3.1.4 LDAP support with JSF.  Although I initially wrote a custom authentication bean, I do not use it any longer.  I am not expert, and I'm sure there's a different way from what I implemented.

---

**(1)** Simple login page (excerpt):

`<h:inputText id="j_username"/>
 <h:inputText type="password" id="j_password" value=""/>
 <h:commandButton name="submit" type="submit" value="Log In" />
 <input type="reset" value="Reset" />`

**(2.1)** In web.xml, I declare a context-param to name the security configuration file (mentioned in step 3 below).
I also declare the Spring security filter chain, which you can read about here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/security-filter-chain.html#filter-chains-with-ns

**(2.2)** In faces-config I declare:
`<el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>`

**(2.3)** In faces-config, I declare a custom UserSession bean with session scope.
UserSession bean has this method:

```java
@PostConstruct  
public void loadAuthorities() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    . . .
    . . .
}
```

**(3)** UserSession bean is referred to *from within the landing page (menu.xhtml)* which is declared in my security config file (declared in web.xml in step 2.1 above):

```xml
<security:form-login default-target-url="/menu.xhtml" always-use-default-target="true"     authentication-failure-url="/denied.xhtml" />                
<security:logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />
```

**(4)** User is authenticated then redirected to menu.xhtml
Menu.xhtml causes UserSession bean to load.

UserSession bean pulls a list of Authorities from the SecurityContext.

UserSession bean provides simple wrappers to check whether a user has authority to view pages and resources:

```java
public boolean isRole(String role) {
    return authorities.contains((String) role);
}

public boolean roleContains(String s);
public boolean roleEndsWith(String s);
. . .
. . .
```